# ActionBarDrawerToggle - toggle hamburger icon to back icon programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

how can toggle between hamburger icon and back icon programmatically ?

with bellow code i can change hamburger icon to back, but i want change it animated

```
actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want more control over the menu/arrow animation, you may want to work with [DrawerArrowDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/DrawerArrowDrawable.html) directly instead of using the ActionBarDrawerToggle class. It takes a bit more work because you have to create your own animators, but it lets you change the drawable state independent of the Navigation drawer.

Edit: Here is a quick MenuArrowDrawable class which extends DrawerArrowDrawable and adds animators. All you need to do is set it as your ActionBar or Toolbar icon and call animateDrawable() when you want it to change state.

```
public class MenuArrowDrawable extends DrawerArrowDrawable {

    private final ValueAnimator mMenuToArrowAnimator;
    private final ValueAnimator mArrowToMenuAnimator;

    public MenuArrowDrawable(Context context) {
        super(context);

        ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener animatorUpdateListener = new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                setPosition((float)animation.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        };

        mMenuToArrowAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
        mMenuToArrowAnimator.setDuration(250);
        mMenuToArrowAnimator.addUpdateListener(animatorUpdateListener);

        mArrowToMenuAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1f, 0f);
        mArrowToMenuAnimator.setDuration(250);
        mArrowToMenuAnimator.addUpdateListener(animatorUpdateListener);
    }

    public void setPosition(float position) {
        if (position >= 1f) {
            setVerticalMirror(true);
        } else if (position <= 0f) {
            setVerticalMirror(false);
        }
        setProgress(position);
    }

    public float getPosition() {
        return getProgress();
    }

    public void animateDrawable(boolean menuToArrow) {
        if (menuToArrow && getPosition() >= 1f) return;
        if (!menuToArrow && getPosition() <= 0f) return;

        ValueAnimator animator = menuToArrow? mMenuToArrowAnimator : mArrowToMenuAnimator;
        if (animator.isRunning()) animator.end();
        animator.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but can you give an example to integrate with actionbar and toggle icon ?

Comment: How to change Arraw direction in this like Left or right

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @Brucelet for help, but need one edit, final code is :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Bind(R.id.toolbar) public Toolbar toolbar;
    @Bind(R.id.drawer_layout) public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    public ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private MenuArrowDrawable drawerArrowDrawable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(this.toolbar);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            this.drawerArrowDrawable = new MenuArrowDrawable(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AppTheme_AppBarOverlay), actionBar);
        }

        this.actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, this.drawerLayout, 0, 0);
        this.drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(this.actionBarDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return this.actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void menuToBack() {
        this.drawerArrowDrawable.animateDrawable(true);
    }

    public void backToMenu() {
        this.drawerArrowDrawable.animateDrawable(false);
    }

    public class MenuArrowDrawable extends DrawerArrowDrawable {
        private final ValueAnimator mMenuToArrowAnimator;
        private final ValueAnimator mArrowToMenuAnimator;
        private ActionBar actionBar;

        public MenuArrowDrawable(Context context, final ActionBar actionBar) {
            super(context);
            this.actionBar = actionBar;

            ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener animatorUpdateListener = new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    setPosition((float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                    if(actionBar != null) {
                        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(MenuArrowDrawable.this);
                    }
                }
            };

            mMenuToArrowAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
            mMenuToArrowAnimator.setDuration(250);
            mMenuToArrowAnimator.addUpdateListener(animatorUpdateListener);

            mArrowToMenuAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1f, 0f);
            mArrowToMenuAnimator.setDuration(250);
            mArrowToMenuAnimator.addUpdateListener(animatorUpdateListener);
        }

        public void setPosition(float position) {
            if (position >= 1f) {
                setVerticalMirror(true);
            } else if (position <= 0f) {
                setVerticalMirror(false);
            }
            setProgress(position);
        }

        public float getPosition() {
            return getProgress();
        }

        public void animateDrawable(boolean menuToArrow) {
            if (menuToArrow && getPosition() >= 1f) return;
            if (!menuToArrow && getPosition() <= 0f) return;

            ValueAnimator animator = menuToArrow? mMenuToArrowAnimator : mArrowToMenuAnimator;
            if (animator.isRunning()) animator.end();
            animator.start();
        }
    }
}
```

`menuToBack()` and `backToMenu()` is ready for this !

Comment: Not sure why you want to call `actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator()` in your AnimatorUpdateListener. You can just call it in your Activity onCreate(). You also probably don't need to still use ActionBarDrawerToggle for anything.

Comment: @Brucelet without it, icon not updated, MenuArrowDrawable create a drawable in each state, i must update actionbar drawable after each state completed

Comment: That's because you left the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` in there which you shouldn't still need.

Comment: @Brucelet if i want keep `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and `MenuArrowDrawable` toggether, can i have a another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.
I have used these codes to change icon  programatically

```
public void createBackButton()
{
    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setNotifCount();
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mToolbar.setTitle("");
    count.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getDrawerToggleDelegate().getThemeUpIndicator());
    mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
}

public void setDefaultActionBar() {

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mToolbar.setTitle("");
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mLvDrawerMenu)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLvDrawerMenu);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mLvDrawerMenu);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Note: I am using this code with AppCompatActivity and Custom Toolbar

Comment: thanks, but i think you are in mistake. i want toggle hamburger icon to back icon without open drawer, please see gmail app, and open an email from list, see drawer icon